# How to sort \nocite entries based on year

Tags: natbib, sorting, bibunits

I am currently organizing my CV and would like to group my publications as published, under review and ongoing work. I use a single `.bib` file and add the papers one by one under each section. I would like to sort the papers in descending order in each section.

I am first sharing a MWE and then giving the entries in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\fancyfootnotetext}[2]{%
  \fancypagestyle{dingens}{%
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\parbox{12cm}{\footnotemark[#1]\footnotesize #2}}%
  }%
  \thispagestyle{dingens}%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\fancypagestyle{CVfooter}
{
 \lhead{}
 \chead{}
 \rhead{}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
}

\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\defaultbibliographystyle{apalike}
\setcitestyle{comma}
\setlength{\bibsep}{8pt}

\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\ \ \ #1.}
\renewcommand\refname{\vspace{-7mm}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{CVfooter}

\noindent \textbf{\textit{\ \ Under Review}}
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{bibunit}
\nocite{paper1}
\nocite{paper2}
\putbib[publications]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

```
@article{paper1,
  title={First article},
  author={Smith, John, and Obra, Daniel,  and Spencer, James},
  journal={A journal},
  volume={45},
  number={7},
  pages={11--46},
  year={2013}
}

@article{paper2,
  title={Second article},
  author={Smith, John and Spencer, James},
  journal={My journal},
  volume={4},
  number={5},
  pages={703--718},
  year={2019}
}
```

[image]

The `.bst` file can be reached at [this link.](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/apalike.bst)

Comment: Give replacing `\nocite{paper1,paper2}` with `\nocite{paper2,paper1}`, followed by a full recompilation cycle, a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I've tried ```\nocite{paper2,paper1}```, but the order did not change.

Comment: I don’t have access to the file `my-apalike.bst`. Have you ascertained that it does *not* sort the bib entries alphabetically?

Comment: My bad! I edited my post and shared a link to access the ```.bst``` file.

Comment: I am looking at ```FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}``` part in the ```.bst``` file. How can I ensure that it sorts in descending order based on year?

Comment: The link you provided points to a file called `apalike.bst`, not `my-apalike.bst`. Is this difference of any relevance?

Comment: There should not be any major difference. I don't quite remember what I changed in the file, but in any case, if you can provide me a solution, I should be able to change my own ```.bst``` file accordingly.

Comment: @ball_jan Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @whitepanda  No, unfortunately! I added the references by hand for the time being.